# Open Layers 3 Click in a layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers

I'm trying to work with lots of layers and each one of them need a different click action but, with all my layers this code is starting to get confuse and messed up. I found out that in Open Layers 2 there was a way to add "on-click" action directly to a layer. It's possible to do the same with Open Layers 3? If it is, there's some example?

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing a map click using `forEachFeatureAtPixel`, `getFeaturesAtPixel` or `hasFeatureAtPixel` each of those methods has a layer filter option:

```
layerFilter: function (layer) { return layer === mylayer; },
```

so you can create separate handlers for each of your layers if you wish.

You can determine the topmost visible layer using

```
var topLayer = map.getLayers().getArray()
  .filter(function(layer) { return layer.getVisible(); })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return a.getZIndex() - b.getZIndex(); })
  .slice(-1)[0];
```

`forEachFeatureAtPixel`, `getFeaturesAtPixel` and `hasFeatureAtPixel` only work for vector layers.

use `if (topLayer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {` to determine if it is a vector layer

For WMS you will probably want to make a getGetFeatureInfo call?

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that I can't just choose a layer, my user will choose. The layer that will be clicked is the layer with the higher z-index and visible. Is there a way to "choose" this without putting lots of ifs? I have more than 100 layers in the map and I'm using WMS and WFS layers with the same map.